# Why does using the wrong calling convention sometimes work?

Tags: c++, winapi, callback, calling-convention

I used "StartServiceCtrlDispatcher" function to register a callback function (called ServiceMain) in windows, but the callback function I declared got compiled with the wrong calling convention.

The thing is that **on some computers**, when the application returned from the callback function, the application crashed, but on other computers the application **did not crash**.

Now, once I found the bug everything worked, but I just don't understand why on some computers it worked correctly without crashing ?

Thanks! :-)

Comment: There's no way you can compile code that passes a callback with the wrong calling convention. Look and see if there's any casts that's forcing the compiler to shut up about it.

Comment: The stack gets imbalanced, esp has the wrong value.  That tends to get fixed by the function epilog, it restores esp from ebp.  All bets are off with the code optimizer enabled.

Comment: This was explained well by Raymond Chen on his blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/05/06/10161590.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is all very Windows-specific, we're not talking standard C++ here.

Checking out the [documentation of `StartServiceDispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686324%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it has only one argument, and is declared as `WINAPI` which in turn means `__stcall` calling convention.

For freestanding functions, [`__stdcall`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa271995%28v=VS.60%29.aspx) is one of two main calling conventions. The other one is [`__cdecl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa271989%28v=VS.60%29.aspx). The machine code level difference is simply who restores the stack pointer: with `__stdcall` it is the function itself, while with `__cdecl` it is the calling code.

When the function actually is `__stdcall` but is invoked as if it was `__cdecl`, the situation is that there are two attempts to restore the stack pointer: one at the exit from the function, and one in the calling code. The one in the function will succeed. Depending on how the attempt in the calling code is done, it can mess things up thoroughly (e.g. if just adding the required offset, treating the stack pointer as relative), or it may have no harmful effect. But it's very likely to create a mess, since the assumption about the stack pointer value on return from the function, is incorrect.

When the function actually is `__cdecl` it will not itself restore the stack pointer, since that is the calling code's responsibility. And if the calling code is treating it as `__stdcall` then the calling code won't restore it either, since from the calling code's view the function is doing that. The result, if you don't get an early crash (because of broken assumptions), should then be that repeated calls, say in a loop, will eat stack space.

It's all very much Undefined Behavior.

And one property of Undefined Behavior is that it can do anything, including apparently working…

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 2):

Calling conventions differ in the details, like which registers are preserved. If you happened to not store anything you still needed in those registers, then it didn't matter that they were erased when they didn't have to be. Similarly, if your calling convention differs about how it deals with return values, if you don't return anything, then it doesn't matter.

Fortunately, x64 only has one calling convention and this whole mess will be in the past.

Comment: I wasn't aware that they abolished calling conventions.  AFAIK in Windows, there's still a Windows calling convention (callee cleans the stack) and a C one (caller cleans the stack).

Comment: Yes, it will all be in the past -- just as soon as the last x86 CPU ceases to exist.  I'm not holding my breath.

Comment: @cHao: Nobody "abolished calling conventions". That would mean having no calling convention at all, which is different from agreeing always to use the same _one_ for at particular architecture. 0 != 1.

Comment: @Henning: If there's only one correct way to do something, it's no longer a convention; it's a standard.

Comment: Also, [operating system may actually fix up the stack](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/15/58973.aspx) in some of the more frequent cases. But you should still always use the correct calling convention, [or it will break if the underlying implementation changes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/16/59415.aspx) or just [simply not work](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/19/60162.aspx). I'm astounded that so many people get this wrong despite the fact that the compiler will complain loudly about mismatched calling conventions.

Comment: Actually, x64 has two. The one you know, and the very simple one for so called leaf functions, i.e. functions that do not call any other functions or raise exceptions. They can have a simplified calling convention, that does not require stack space for the preservation of certain registers, etc. That convention is not required, so I doubt it will be used a lot.

Comment: @In silico: Only if the calling convention was declared properly in a header. This is not always the case for callbacks, IME. Sometimes only the documentation "declares" them and the function taking the callback declares it as void* or some such.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis: True, but that's not the case here since the Windows API headers does declare the calling convention for callback types properly (via `WINAPI` or `CALLBACK`, which both expand to `__stdcall`).

Answer (score 1):

The computers where the application crashed might have been using .NET Framework version 4.

Have a look at the following article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee941656.aspx

It states the following under Interoperability - Platform Invoke:

"To improve performance in interoperability with unmanaged code, incorrect calling conventions in a platform invoke now cause the application to fail. In previous versions, the marshaling layer resolved these errors up the stack."

Answer (score 0):

This is all related to what is current in the memory. Let's assume you have two functions like this:

```
void stdcall f1(...) { ... }

void cdecl f2(...) { ... }
```

`stdcall` is Windows calling convention, while `cdecl` is used by most compilers. The difference between them is who owns the responsibility to clear the stack after the call. In `stdcall`, the callee (`f1`, or `f2`) does, in `cdecl`, the caller does.

The stack, after all, is filled with unknown values. Therefore, when it gets cleaned up (wrongly), the next value that you access in the stack is undetermined. It could very well be an acceptable value, or it could be a very bad one. This is, in principle, how stack overflow (the bug, not the site) works.